# How to use React components as part of legacy HTML/JS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an old web application running with HTML/JS.
I have created a new react application and my goal is to start developing new features / pages using React, and implement them in the current application.

The main goal is to use React components outside react, for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> My old web applciation</title>
// Imports for my react app / components
</head>
<body>

<!-- Old staff -->

<Footer someProp="1"/>

</body>
</html>
```

What I have so far:

- For full-page features I used Iframe (and created a route in React for it)
- Using element ID, e.g::

and in react:

```
const GiveItem = ({ ...props }) => {

  console.log("init give item component");

  return (
    <section>
     Give Item
    </section>
  );
};

try {
  const domContainer = document.querySelector('#giveItem');
  render(e(GiveItem), domContainer);
} catch (e) {
  console.error('Failed to render give item', e);
}

export default GiveItem;
```

Is there any legitimate way to "export" react components to HTML (outside react) and use them as native components like:

```
<GiveItem someProp="1"/>
```

Using Vue I managed to do it, just by wrapping the highest-level element with:

```
    <div id="vapp">

 .... My old code

<VueComponent />
```

So back to the question - How I can show/use React components in different parts of legacy app as native HTML components?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will divide my answer into 3 parts:

1. simple inclusion of react in general
2. make your example work
3. modules

*(I will use [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) below. You can use [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/) as well, I assume you are familiar with these.)*

### 1. simple inclusion of react in general

See [Add React to a Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).

*index.html*:

```
<html><head>
    <title>My old web applciation</title>
</head><body>

<h1>old stuff</h1>
<p>Some old HTML content.</p>

<!-- add a container, where you want to include react components -->
<div id="injected-react-content"></div>

<!-- import the react libraray -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<!-- import your react component -->
<script src="GiveItem.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

*GiveItem.js*:
*(modified from JSX to JS. For JSX see section 2.)*

```
const GiveItem = (props) => {
    console.log("init give item component");
    return React.createElement(
        "section",
        null,
        "Give item content"
    );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#injected-react-content');

ReactDOM.render( React.createElement(GiveItem), domContainer );
```

### 2. make your example work

Your component uses JSX. You need to transpile it to JS, using *babel*.

*GiveItem.**jsx***:
*(it is not necessary to call it .jsx, but it makes sense)*

```
const GiveItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <section>
            Give Item
        </section>
    );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#injected-react-content');
ReactDOM.render( React.createElement(GiveItem), domContainer );
```

Install *babel*:

```
yarn add @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx @babel/preset-react --dev
```

Transpile your JSX file `./src/GiveItem.jsx` into a JS file in `./dist/GiveItem.js`:

```
yarn babel ./src/GiveItem.jsx --presets=@babel/preset-react --out-dir dist
```

(the `dist` folder will be created if it doesn't exist)

If you now copy the index.html into `./dist`,
you should have the same code as in section 1.,
and opening `./dist/index.html` in the browser should work.

### 3. modules

Of course, you would want to import other react components and sub-components.
*(And you probably don't want to import everything individually with `<script>` tags.)*

#### if an environment is set up already

Maybe your old app already runs in a yarn (or npm) environment, then you might be fine with

- install `yarn add react` and `yarn add react-dom`
- removing the two `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react...` lines (as react is probably already imported inside your components),
- then import some root component (instead of `GiveItem.js` before),
  where you do the `ReactDOM.render(...)` and import further modules:

E.g.:

*index.html*:

```
<!-- import your react component -->
<script type="module" src="EntryIntoReactWorld.js"></script>
```

*EntryIntoReactWorld.js*:

```
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent';
import SomeOtherComponent from './SomeOtherComponent';

const ReactRoot = props => {
  return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      React.createElement(SomeComponent, null),
      React.createElement(SomeOtherComponent, null)
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(ReactRoot),
    document.querySelector('#injected-react-content')
);
```

#### if environment is not set up already

If your old app is *not* already running in a yarn (or npm) environment, you have to set one up.

Unfortunately, **this is not trivial**.
*(I tried to write a short working minimal example here, but I failed.)*

For that you have to enter the world of [Javascript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).
But modern browsers don't allow many things from the local file system.
(e.g. see [CORS problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197495/javascript-modules-and-cors), [MIME problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ), ...)

You have to install a server for development. You might start with e.g. [http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server), but there you probably still will have problems, so I suggest to already start with writing a `server.js` file and use [node http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).
*(Maybe [expressjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) as well. It is not necessary, but everybody uses it, and it is easier to find help and tutorials.)*

You also might need [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/).

Of course you also have to install `yarn add react` and `yarn add react-dom`.

Comment: Wowww! What an answer! Thanks. My legacy project is simple HTML/JS Based legacy app, no npm or yarn. I kinda lost you from the "modules" part

Comment: For inline babel see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69607103/react-component-not-displayed-in-html/69620365#69620365: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>` ... `<script type="text/babel">...`